# Appending <p> to <div> in popup.html doesn't show up(Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

While building a simple chrome extension, I've appended a `<p>` element to `<div>` element in popup.js using,

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id : "ExtId",
    title : "Copy This",
    contexts: ["all"],
});
function copyThis(info) {
    var pNode = document.createElement("p");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(info.selectionText);
    pNode.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("mainDiv").appendChild(pNode);
}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(copyThis);
```

manifest.json is

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CopyThis",
  "description": "This extension copies selected text",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
      "contextMenus",
      "clipboardWrite"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action" : {
      "default_popup" : "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
  "16": "icon16.png",
  "48": "icon48.png",
  "128": "icon128.png"
  }
}
```

popup.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CopyThis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv">
    <p id ="pID">this is one</p>
    <p id="pID2"></p>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, my aim is to make copied text appear in popup.html

When I click on extension icon, copied text doesn't show up.But when I inspect popup.html, the added `<p>` element is present.
Am I missing to add something?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: BTW: When you want a only a single text node child, [`pNode.textContent = "some text";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is a bit more efficient than individually creating the text node and appending it. "Setting this property on a node removes all of its children and replaces them with a single text node with the given value."

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.